# Getting AccessibleName property

Tags: java, properties, javafx

I have a control and I need to find it's [Accessible Name Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/accessibility/AccessibleContext.html#accessibleName). I did so like this :

```
Component myComponent = (Component)myControl;
string accessName = myComponent.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName();
```

This works like a charm in java but when it comes to `JavaFx` I can't find this property.
 I've looked online but there's not a lot of online support for this specific request. So much that I can't even find the equivalent in `JavaFx`.

Anybody knows how it's called or how to access it ? This would help a lot my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think accessibility is currently implemented for JavaFX and if it were I don't know if it would make use of `javax.accessibility`.

From the [JavaFX Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html):

> Oracle is committed to providing accessibility support in its product offerings, and JavaFX is planned to be fully accessibility compliant as part of the JDK 8 release.

The roadmap also says:

> The following information is intended to outline our general product direction. It is intended for information purposes only, and may not be incorporated into any contract. It is not a commitment to deliver any material, code, or functionality, and should not be relied upon in making purchasing decisions. The development, release, and timing of any features or functionality described remains at the sole discretion of Oracle.

You are unlikely to receive an official response from Oracle on StackOverflow.  You may receive more information if you ask the question on an [official Oracle forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1385) or on the [JavaFX development mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).